# Image displaying under navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have an image next to my vertical navbar but it's being displayed under it.

This is how I'm doing it

```css
    body
    {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        background-color: #333;
    }

    .element
    {
        display:inline-block;
        float:left;
    }

    #wrapper
    {
        position:absolute;
        height:100%;
        width:200px;
        bottom:0px;
        background-color:#0F4D92;
    }

    nav
    {
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -75px;
        position: fixed;
    }

    ul
    {
        list-style-type: none;
        width: 200px;
        height: 40px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="element" id="wrapper">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="withdraw.php">Withdraw</a></li>
                <li><a href="deposit.php">Deposit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <img class="element" src="../bg.jpg"/>
```

Yet, this is how it looks: 
[image: Behind]

As you can see the image is behind the navbar. I can't just use a margin because I need an element with the size of the gray space so I can have the image in the center of that space. So how can I fix this?

Comment: it would probably be a lot easier if you wouldn't have that navbar absolutely positioned. Then you wouldn't need to float your image either.
If you really need it absolutely positioned, just add a margin.

Comment: @Pavlin Updated the post, I can't add a margin.

Comment: well then changing the positioning of your navbar to relative is probably your best bet.

Comment: @Pavlin The navbar height becomes 0 if I do that.

Comment: yes, that is happening because it is trying to take up 100% of the body, if you set html, body { min-height: 100%; } that should be resolved. Although that can sometimes result in some very strange behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gathering from what you want to achieve, I took the liberty to change up your markup and made you a working copy. Less complicated than what you were trying to do I think. I hope this helps in some way.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #333;
}
.element {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
}
nav,
.imgWrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}
nav {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #0F4D92;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
nav > * {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.imgWrapper {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 80%;
}
.imgWrapper > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="withdraw.php">Withdraw</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="deposit.php">Deposit</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="imgWrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x2000" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your wrapper for the navbar is `position: absolute;` which means that none of the other elements will interact with it. Maybe try using `position: relative;` instead.

Comment: @NendoTake This makes the height of the navbar 0.

Comment: Another idea would be to add `margin-left: 200px;` to the body css class

Answer (score 0):

By the way you are doing it one solution is to give `.element` a left margin, but you will always have to set a margin if you want to display something next to your navbar (because its absolute positioned):

```
.element
{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 210px;
}
```

Comment: I can't do that because I want to display the image in the middle of the gray space so I need an element with the size of that gray space.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper position causing this problem. You must change it to relative. You also need to change the following:

```css
 ##wrapper {
   position: relative;
 }
 #wrapper {
   float: left;
   width: 250px;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
 .element {
   float: right;
 }
 #wrapper,
 .element {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
 }
```